# compare 2 csv files pandas by column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files

*one.csv*

| Supplier Code | Cost Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.25 |
| 2 | 1.25 |
| 3 | 3.25 |

*two.csv*

| Supplier Code | Cost Price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.25 |
| 2 | 1.75 |
| 3 | 3.75 |
| 5 | 1.25 |

So `one.csv` is compared to `two.csv`

ONE.csv has about 500 values in 2 columns. TWO.csv has 10000 values in 2 columns. The shape of the files is same. Code column does not change, but is either present or absent in ONE.csv/TWO.csv

What I am looking to do  is:

1. Find subset of the all Supplier Code in ONE.csv that are present in TWO.csv, with Cost Price updated from TWO.csv
2. Output that to CSV file

Expected output:

```
Supplier Code,Cost Price
1,2.25
2,1.75
3,3.75
```

This is what I have tried...

```
one = pd.read_csv(ONE_PATH)
two = pd.read_csv(TWO_PATH)

present_in_two = one[one['Supplier Code'].isin(two['Supplier Code'])]

print(present_in_two.head())
```

I get:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Supplier Code, Cost Price]
Index: []
```

Edit: Corrected typo..

Comment: I can't reproduce that output based on this data. Maybe you're not parsing the CSVs correctly? Please make a [mre]; for specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). See also [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: Why should be in output `1,1.25`? Shouldn't it be `1,2.25`?

Comment: If you created a sample, you should of course check what the result of applying your code to the sample is. This question is not possible because **sample does not cause the result you experienced.**

Comment: Hi all, Thank you all for your time. I solved the problem, the issue was actually with cleaning up the data. The question was wrong in essence. Given the question is locked, I am unable to post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your use case.

Merge the two dataframes on key `Supplier Code` and select only the key column from `df_one` when merging.

The data form `df_two` would be selected which also exist on `df_one`

```
dict_one = {"Supplier Code": [1, 2, 3], "Cost Price": [2.25, 1.25, 3.25]}
dict_two = {"Supplier Code": [1, 2, 3, 5], "Cost Price": [2.25, 1.75, 3.75, 1.25]}


df_one = pd.DataFrame(dict_one)
df_two = pd.DataFrame(dict_two)

df_merged = pd.merge(df_one[["Supplier Code"]], df_two, on="Supplier Code")
df_merged
```

```
        Supplier Code   Cost Price
    0   1               2.25
    1   2               1.75
    2   3               3.75
```

Comment: This seems to not exactly match the original requirement as for Supplier Code 3 the result is not as requested. (3.25 vs 3.75). Since you seeded your example not per datasets provided in opening post.

Comment: When changed the solution is perfectly valid though. Unfortunately I cannot edit the post due to requirement of minimum 6 characters needing to be changed :-(

Comment: Code was correct, I used wrong data. I have edited to fix it

Comment: Hi all, Thank you all for your time. I solved the problem, the issue was actually with cleaning up the data. I will accept this as answer, for the effort. The question was wrong in essence. Given the question is locked, I am unable to post the solution.